# Migrate from (pirate) windows 8.1 Pro 64Bit VL, to (legit) retail

Tags: windows-8.1

I have up until now, been running a VL copy of 8.1Pro64Bit, but would like to switch to retail, I have purchased a retail copy and created a bootable USB, but how would I change to this?

I want to do so, in order to get Windows Media Centre.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried simply changing the license key?  You would need a retail Windows 8.1 Professional key.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows easy transfer to migrate your stuff from your current windows 8.1 - Do a full backup as well just to make sure. Format the HDD and reinstall your new purchased copy of Windows 8.1 with your new legit licence key. Use Windows easy transfer again to import your profile/settings and data back.